# Using DEFAULT keyword in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I use this library https://github.com/go-pg/pg .

I have a simple model.

```golang
type ChatAdmin struct {
    Id int64
    TgId int
    CreatedAt time.Time `pg:"default:now()"`
}
```

With this code I'm trying to insert an instance to the table.

```golang
func (m Model) createChatAdminByTgUserID(tgUserId int) (ChatAdmin, error) {
    admin := new(ChatAdmin)
    admin.TgId = tgUserId

    _, err := db.Model(admin).SelectOrInsert(admin)
    return *admin, err
}
```

After insert, I see row in table where created_at == NULL.
Why does `default:now()` not working?

I've tried to set it with `sql:"default:now()"` but it did no helped.

My PostgreSQL version is: 11.66 running on Ubuntu

This is CREATE TABLE log:

`"chat_admins" ("id" bigserial, "tg_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`

This is from heroku dataclips after inserting:

[image]

Comment: have you checked the query it generates?

Comment: The default is used when [creating tables](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#DB.CreateTable), not when querying.

Comment: @Peter, of course, I use default when creating a table. `Default` defines default value for row element, if it is not set during insert.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky, I've checked,`"chat_admins" ("id" bigserial, "tg_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`

Comment: You state: _After insert, I see row in table where created_at == NULL_  . This contradicts your `CREATE TABLE` statement where `created_at` has a `NOT NULL` constraint. Are you connected to the same database / using the same schema /search_path / whatever?

Comment: @clamp yes, i'm using the same database

Comment: That's not possible, you should see _ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint_ . Try a simple `INSERT INTO chat_admins VALUES(5,5,NULL);`

Comment: Despite the contradiction of seeing null values and having a not null constraint, I think there is another misconception here with what defining a default means. It **does not** define a value to use in place of null on insert, it defines a value on insert when the column is NOT mentioned. If the column is mentioned or the case where no column is mentioned then NULL is a perfectly good value.  Thus the example "INSERT INTO chat_admins VALUES(5,5,NULL);" would attempt to insert null into the 3rd column, but INSERT INTO chat_admins(id, tg_id)  VALUES(5,5);" would pickup the default value.

Comment: @Belayer exactly, and that is what happens given the table definition of the OP. Inserting (5,5) triggers the default just as expected, whereas an attempt to insert (5,5,NULL) errors out. That‘s why i think the table definition can‘t be the one presented by the OP. Otherwise that row would not be there.